# How to get Non Null 1st String Value returned from a list of Strings in ASC Order?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

Can I do something like this?

***Edit***:

```
public static String GetFirstNotNull(params string[] theStrings)
{
    foreach(String sOut in theStrings)
    {
        if (sOut != null)
        {
            return sOut;
            break;
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

And than use it like this?

`string string6 = "Blah";`

`string theFirstStringThatIsNotNullInList = GetFirstNotNull(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6, string7);`

Will it than return "Blah"??

Is there a better, or even quicker way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you try it first?

Comment: I have it doesn't seem to work.  Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: What's the problem? Also, it might be an asp thing (I come from c#) but what's with the `!s`? Maybe you mean`s != null`?

Comment: `s => !s == null` well, that's a *compiler error* (actually, that's just one of the errors) so *listen* to what the compiler is saying and/or post code reproducing the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call a method like you did you'd need:

```
public static String GetFirstNotNull(params string[] theStrings)
{
    ...
}
```

The `params` keyword allows supplying any number of parameters which are automagically converted to an array.

`!s == null` is close but doesn't compile, it's `s != null`.

Also, this is commonly called a "coalesce" operation.

Comment: Have updated question, I believe this approach will work, but seems a bit slow for it's purpose I suppose...

Comment: I don't think there's a quicker way really. How slow exactly is it?